# Intent closes app instead of moving to next activity (android studio using kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been facing this issue for a while now. Quite new to Kotlin!
My intent closes the app instead of proceeding to a new activity.
Tried using coroutines, handlers, etc. but the problem seems to be with the intent, or the second activities scripts.
I've provided most of the relevant codes below.

SplashActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.projectmanager
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
        val typeFace : Typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "coolvetica rg.otf")
        val tv_app_name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_app_name)
        tv_app_name.typeface = typeFace
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            startActivity(Intent(this, Intro::class.java))
            finish()
        }, 2500)
    }
    fun switchActivities(){
        val i = Intent(this@SplashActivity, Intro::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
        finish()
    }
}
```

activity_splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/wp3238529"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/splash_screen_title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Intro.kt:

```
package com.example.projectmanager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowManager
class Intro : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }
}
```

activity_intro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/intro_background"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Intro">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_title_marginTop"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/intro_screen_title_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_image_marginTop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_task_image"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_get_started_text_marginTop"
        android:text="@string/lets_get_started_text"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:textSize="@dimen/intro_screen_get_started_text_size"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/intro_text_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/intro_text_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_text_marginTop"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/intro_text_line_spacing_extra"
        android:text="@string/intro_text_description"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        android:textSize="@dimen/intro_text_size"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_sign_in_btn_marginTop"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button_rounded"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_screen_sign_in_btn_marginTop"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/btn_marginStartEnd"
        android:background="@drawable/white_button_rounded"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_paddingTopBottom"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size"/>

</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjectManager"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Intro"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat errors:

```
2022-09-27 20:37:15.995 12470-12470/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.projectmanager, PID: 12470
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectmanager/com.example.projectmanager.Intro}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65 in com.example.projectmanager:layout/activity_intro: Binary XML file line #65 in com.example.projectmanager:layout/activity_intro: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65 in com.example.projectmanager:layout/activity_intro: Binary XML file line #65 in com.example.projectmanager:layout/activity_intro: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65 in com.example.projectmanager:layout/activity_intro: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 35: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030342 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f0f0009com.example.projectmanager:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar, id=0x7f0f0008com.example.projectmanager:style/AppTheme], Themes=[com.example.projectmanager:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar, forced, com.example.projectmanager:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5929)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1072)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:166)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:141)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:80)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:75)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:211)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:129)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1569)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1065)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.projectmanager.Intro.onCreate(Intro.kt:10)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269)
2022-09-27 20:37:15.995 12470-12470/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: please post your error log

Comment: What error do u get in the logs? I suspect something wrong in the "Intro" class

Comment: Added the logcat errors in the post